# Chrome-like inline search highlighting in Safari?

Tags: safari, google-chrome, search

I just switched over from using Chrome to Safari and I really like it, but I find the search function in Safari very limiting.

Are there any extensions for Chrome-like highlighting in Safari? For those of you that are unfamiliar with it, I'm referring to ability to highlight all instances found on the page. Also, a great feature of Chrome highlighting is when it shows the instances on the scroll bar, so I know where the keyword is most densely (or sparingly) used.
More details on this: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/13651/is-there-a-name-for-the-ui-that-marks-key-positions-in-a-scroll-bar